# Why do Selenium IDE scripts I have refined behave differently within Selenium WebDriver executions?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

Specifically, when I supply a command and XPath to an object within a frame, the IDE can interact with the object without having to execute the "selectFrame" command.  When I run the same sequence of commands within a WebDriver execution:

```
| waitForVisible | target |
| click | target |
```

The WebDriver produces a stack trace indicating that the object is not visible and cannot be interacted with.  I have to update my script with the additional step of:

```
| selectFrame | frame |
| waitForVisible | target |
| click | target |
```

Does the IDE use some kind of Javascript Injection similar to the RC to emulate the commands within the IDE?

Answer (score 0):

The IDE and web driver follow similar coding paths, but are not exactly the same. So the commands might always be fully in sync depending on the version. We had a problem where our IDE was able to pass variables among tests in a test Suite but our version of the stand alone (2.37) did not support this (it does 2.38+).

However WebDriver also uses native commands and breaks away from Javascript injection which actually gives you more power (avoids Single Host origin policy for one) in some regards.